# Creating string by combining value from combobox and serial count

Tags: java

Right now my output of count is 0 for every element in combobox i.e it is like B10,B20,B30(B is the default value,next term is the value from database, and 0 is showing the count in this concatenated string)...my count is not increasing

What should I do so that my count increase when I select a value from Jcombobox
and press the button i.e.I get B10,B11,B12,B20,B21,B22,B30,B31,B32

```
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           String str = ae.getActionCommand();
           if (str.equals("GENERATE PART NO. :")) {
           try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/d03", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();

            String s = "select value from user1 where Userdata='" + jc.getSelectedItem() + "'";

            rs = st.executeQuery(s);
            t1.getText();
            if (rs.next()) {
                int j = 0;
                String add1 = rs.getString("value");
                t1.setEditable(false);

                String str9 = new String();
                str9 = "B" + add1; //B is the default value, add1 is the value from database  

                String str10 = new String();
                str10 = str9 + j;
                String query = "select MC from final";
                ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    if (str10.equals(rs1)) {
                        j = j + 1;
                        j=new Integer(j+1);
                        t1.setText(str10);
                    } else {
                        t1.setText(str10);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/d03", "root", "");

                String s1 = ("insert into final(MC)values(?)");
                PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(s1);
                pstm.setString(1, t1.getText());
                int rowi = pstm.executeUpdate();

                if (rowi > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DATA INSERTED");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:
Move `str10 = str9 + j;` into `while` body.

Your (fragment of the) code should look like:

```
  /*  if */while(rs.next()) {
       int j = 0;
        String add1 = rs.getString("value");
        t1.setEditable(false);

   // String str9; //= new String(); redundant
        String str9 = "B" + add1; //B is the default value add1 is the value from database  
        String str10 = str9;
        String query = "select MC from final";
        ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs1.next()) {   
            if (str10.equals(rs1.getString("MC")) {
                j++; //j = j + 1;
               // j=new Integer(j+1); you simply increment j twice
                str10 = str9 + j;// EDITED LINE!
            }
            t1.setText(str10);  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: the last value is still showing 0(the count one) i.e. B10(for first element of combobox)B20(for second element) and so on.it should increment but it is not increasing

Comment: @user6443988 try now please

Comment: @user6443988 I hope you took corrected code with line commented `// EDITED LINE!`?

Comment: you can try any other approaches if you like to

Comment: @user6443988 1. I guess the `while(rs.next())` should be instead `if(rs.next())`,2. what does mean `t1.getText();` - value discarded? And the  main issue : Look at the fixed text  above ....

Comment: @user6443988 Sorry,I slightly mixed up, please use corrected text `if (str10.equals(rs1.getString("MC")) {` instead  of `if (str10.equals(rs1) {` you compared  string with result set... Hope it's ok   this time- ...

Comment: @user6443988 you're welcome. Also, please upvote the answer and mark it as appropriate (if you don't mind ).